# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: data/data/c.test.com/databases/database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I designed an Android app, but if click in the imageview and show image in the new activity it forces a close.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an 
already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: data/data/c.test.com/databases/database
```

database:

```
public String Display(int row,int fild){
    Cursor cu= mydb.query("ps", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cu.moveToPosition(row);
    String name=cu.getString(fild);
    cu.close();
    return name;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seems too generous on tags. Please give us a reason on tagging javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The error means you called `mydb.close()` in your code.

Since you are starting a new activity, this means your `onPause` method is called.

You should open the database again in the new activity.

Comment: I close in activity by: 
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  db.close();
 } and open in new activity by :db.open();

Comment: how exactly do you open in new activity? are you sure  it is executed before  the exception occurs ?

Comment: I no use database in new activity.

Comment: i suggest you edit the question and add the code where yiu use the db